# AWS - how do we send requests to specific server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a multiple sites for various location like UK,BE,US etc... If i use the US site it need to be hit only US region server only. Like wise UK means UK server etc.. Is this possible to achieve using AWS server.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you need is Geolocation routing. The AWS documentation for this is found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html).

En excerpt from this page is:

> Geolocation routing lets you choose the resources that serve your traffic based on the geographic location of your users, meaning the location that DNS queries originate from. For example, you might want all queries from Europe to be routed to an ELB load balancer in the Frankfurt region.